# Draggable from jquery ui works on the jsPlumb website but when i save the complete webpage locally the drag and drop stops working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsplumb

I am looking at this jsPlumb example: http://jsplumb.org/jquery/flowchartConnectorsDemo.html

You will see that the drag and drop of the boxes works perfectly, but when you save the complete webpage locally the drag and drop doesn't work anymore.

I have tried changing the paths to the JS files, i tried using latest versions of jqueryUi and jquery instead of the ones from the website, with no success. I have also tried saving the page with Safari and Chrome and FF, the same thing happens.

This happens with any of their examples, and you will also notice that on the local copy, the left-side window (the one where you can select the render type and the library...etc), appears TWICE.

Also the drag and drop works on that window but not on the 4 squares from the example.

Can anyone help me with this please, or can direct me to some working examples (that can work on a local copy).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but this happened many times with me when I save the webpage using Google Chrome and Firefox, but when I save it using IE (select: webpage, complete) the webpage works fine offline. This is not the first time I have saved pages, and many times I have experienced the same thing, saving with Google Chrome and Firefox "break" something, while in IE it works as it should.

I myself am not an IE user, but when I need to save a webpage to check its functionality offline, I use IE for saving.

Answer (score 0):

The pages on jsPlumb.org are not really designed to be saved locally.  Although I can why you might want to use one of them as the basis for your own app.  Have you considered checking out the code from GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

Get the code from https://github.com/sporritt/jsplumb/. Extract the downloaded code and goto demo/jquery folder. From here you can run the demos.